# Github Pull Request Banners

Tags: github, github-api

How do you apply a banner below a pull request, travis-ci style, with the github api?

This green box below the description, (changes to other colours as well, though)

[image: Travis-ci PR Banner]

Comment: Checked the blog? => https://github.com/blog/843-the-merge-button

Comment: They are built in ones, the travis ones are third party. @ekremkrc